# Avoid looping a pandas dataframe keeping track of remaining inventory

Tags: pandas

I currently loop through a pandas dataframe that contains orders so that I can remove the ordered items from inventory and keep track of which order may not get filled (this is part of a reservation system).
I'd love to avoid the loop and do this in a more pythonic/panda-esque way but haven't been able to come up with anything that let's me get to the level of granularity I like. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Here's a much simplified version of this.

Examples of the input would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def get_inventory():

    df_inv = pd.DataFrame([{'sku': 'A1', 'remaining': 1000},
         {'sku': 'A2', 'remaining': 600},
         {'sku': 'A3', 'remaining': 180},
         {'sku': 'B1', 'remaining': 800},
         {'sku': 'B2', 'remaining': 500},
         ], columns=['sku', 'remaining']).set_index('sku')

    df_inv.loc[:, 'allocated'] = 0
    df_inv.loc[:, 'reserved'] = 0
    df_inv.loc[:, 'missed'] = 0

    return df_inv


def get_reservations():
    skus = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2']
    res = []
    for i in range(0, 1000, 1):
        res.append({'order_id': i, 
                    'sku': random.choice(skus),
                    'number_of_items_reserved': 1})    

    df_res = pd.DataFrame(res, 
         columns=['order_id', 'sku', 'number_of_items_reserved'])

    return df_res
```

Inventory:

```
df_inv = get_inventory()
print(df_inv)


     remaining  allocated  reserved  missed
sku                                        
A1        1000          0         0       0
A2         600          0         0       0
A3         180          0         0       0
B1         800          0         0       0
B2         500          0         0       0
```

Reservations:

```
df_res = get_reservations()
print(df_res.head(10))

   order_id sku  number_of_items_reserved
0         0  A3                         1
1         1  B1                         1
2         2  A3                         1
3         3  A1                         1
4         4  B1                         1
5         5  B1                         1
6         6  B1                         1
7         7  B1                         1
8         8  A3                         1
9         9  B1                         1
```

The logic to allocate reservations to inventory looks roughly like this:
(this is the part I'd love to replace)

```
"""
df_inv: inventory grouped (indexed) by sku (style and size)
df_res: reservations by order id for a style and size
"""
df_inv = get_inventory()
df_res = get_reservations()

for i, res in df_res.iterrows():

    sku = res['sku']
    n_items = res['number_of_items_reserved']

    inv = df_inv[df_inv.index == sku]['remaining'].values[0]

    df_inv.loc[(df_inv.index == sku), 'reserved'] += n_items

    if (inv-n_items) >= 0:
        df_inv.loc[(df_inv.index == sku), 'allocated'] += n_items
        df_inv.loc[(df_inv.index == sku), 'remaining'] -= n_items
    else:
        df_inv.loc[(df_inv.index == sku), 'missed'] += n_items
```

Results:

```
     remaining  allocated  reserved  missed
sku                                        
A1         817        183       183       0
A2         390        210       210       0
A3           0        180       210      30
B1         613        187       187       0
B2         290        210       210       0
```

Comment: Can you add a sample input and expected out to this question.

Comment: Just added sample dataframes. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get way without looping due to the [intrinsic data alignment](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures) in Pandas.

```
df_inv = get_inventory()
df_res = get_reservations()
```

Creates series with the index of 'sku'

```
n_items = df_res.groupby('sku')['number_of_items_reserved'].sum()
shortage = df_inv['remaining'] - n_items 
enough_inv = shortage > 0
```

Because Pandas does intrinsic data alignment and df_inv index is 'sku' and the created series above index is 'sku', these calculations are done by 'sku'.  Using boolean indexing to determine which 'sku's has enough inventory to increment `allocated` and decrement `remaining` or increment `missed`.

```
df_inv['reserved'] += n_items
df_inv.loc[enough_inv,'allocated'] += n_items
df_inv.loc[enough_inv,'remaining'] -= n_items
df_inv.loc[~enough_inv,'missed'] -= shortage
df_inv.loc[~enough_inv,'allocated'] += n_items + shortage
df_inv.loc[~enough_inv,'remaining'] = 0

print(df_inv)
```

Output:

```
     remaining  allocated  reserved  missed
sku                                        
A1       815.0      185.0       185     0.0
A2       410.0      190.0       190     0.0
A3         0.0      180.0       200    20.0
B1       586.0      214.0       214     0.0
B2       289.0      211.0       211     0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Seems to me though that for SKUs where I don't have enough to fulfill all orders, I end up allocating 0 reservations? I just updated the dataframe setup to include more reservations and restricted the inventory for one SKU so I likely can't fulfill a few orders.

Comment: Yeah... I was thinking we need a bit more robust test data.

Comment: @ClausHerther I found a typo in the solution and fixed it.

Comment: Thx Scott, I had seen that and fixed it as well. Still, same results though, I end up missing all reservations for A3, even though I can allocate 180.

Comment: @ClausHerther Try that.